# Angular 6, d3 v5 mouse event, ERROR TypeError: this.setAttribute is not a function

Tags: angular, d3.js

d3's `on` function can bind some mouse events, like `.on('click',callbackfunction)`, `.on('mouseover',callbackfunction)`..etc.

For example:

```
this.state.svg
      .selectAll("rect")
      .data(this.state.data)
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .on('mouseover',(d,i)=>{
        d3.select(<any>this)
        .attr('fill','#0C9CDF');
      })
```

`this` can directly manipulate the current dom(or svg) object, but not working properly in angular:

```
core.js:1673 ERROR TypeError: this.setAttribute is not a function
    at AppComponent.<anonymous> (attr.js:17)
    at Selection.each (each.js:5)
    at Selection.attr (attr.js:53)
    at SVGRectElement.<anonymous> (app.component.ts:269)
    at SVGRectElement.<anonymous> (on.js:27)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:3811)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
    at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:498)
```

It may be that angular uses `this` as the `component's` `this` during operation, and how to specify it correctly.

[D3 Mouse Events](http://bl.ocks.org/WilliamQLiu/76ae20060e19bf42d774)

Comment: Can you describe what exactly you are trying to do inside `mosueover` event handler?

Comment: Change the color of the bar chart(rectangle) when the mouse moves over the bar chart.

Comment: d3 can generate `data.length` bar chart according to the `.data() function`.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the problem is in `arrow functions expression`, it will take the component `this` object, you must use `Simple function`:

```
  .on('mouseover',function(d,i)=>{
        d3.select(<any>this)
        .attr('fill','#0C9CDF');
      })
```